# In JavaScript, the Math object- why does it not process commas in numbers?

Tags: javascript, object, math, numbers

I have the example of a mortgage calculator, when I enter a mortgage amount such as: 500,000 then the result is Not a Number. Obviously if enter 500000 it works fine. Is this a thing that happens specifically with the Math object or is it a general thing in JavaScript that any number with a comma will appear as "Not a Number"?

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Comma has other uses in the rest of JavaScript:

- It separates function parameters and arguments
- it separates array and object elements
- it separates variable declarations
- it's the comma operator in expressions

It would be difficult for it also to be used as a character in numbers. For instance, you can call a function with two numeric arguments:

```
funcName(123,456)
```

or create an array of numbers:

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

Perhaps they could have designed the language to require a space around the comma in these cases, but they didn't. JavaScript adopted this syntax from other languages (e.g. C), and historically this has not been a concern of language designers. There are some languages that allow you to put space or underscore in numbers to separate the thousands groups, but I can't think of any that allows commas. Even COBOL, which tries to be the most accomodating of using human-oriented notation, doesn't allow them.